# How to inject viewmodel factory by dagger 2

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, android-viewmodel

Trying to create a view model in a fragment by providing the factory with a dagger but app crashes with error. Move injection to another lifecycle doesn't work

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.bigproject.planyourlife, PID: 13934
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property factory has not been initialized
    at com.bigproject.planyourlife.view.SignupFragment.getFactory(SignupFragment.kt:27)
```

ViewModel

```
class SignupViewModel(private val service: AuthService) : ViewModel() {
private var email: String = ""
private var password: String = ""
private val _uiState = MutableStateFlow<SignupState>(SignupState.Success(null))
val uiState: StateFlow<SignupState> = _uiState

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class Factory @Inject constructor(
    private val service: AuthService
) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        require(modelClass == SignupViewModel::class)
        return SignupViewModel(service) as T
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
class SignupFragment : Fragment(R.layout.signup_page) {

    private val binding by viewBinding(SignupPageBinding::bind)
    private val signupViewModel: SignupViewModel by viewModels {
        factory
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var factory: SignupViewModel.Factory

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        context.appComponent.inject(this)
        super.onAttach(context)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you correctly bound `SignupViewModel.Factory` and `SignupFragment` to your modules? Are you obtaining `SignupFragment` using DI?

Comment: @momt99 I don't obtain any fragment using DI, I don't quite understand how this is supposed to work, because I recently started learning dagger

Answer (score 1):

First, create a module for your ViewModelFactory. This is important for you to provide ViewModelFactory for dagger.

*ViewModelModule.kt*

```
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {

    @Binds
    abstract fun provideViewModelFactory(factory: Factory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    // Binds your viewmodel in here.
}
```

Next, you need to include that module in your component. Specifically here is `AppComponent`.

*AppComponent.kt*

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ViewModelModule::class, YourFragmentModule::class, YourActivityModule::class, ...])
interface AppComponent {

    @Component.Factory
    abstract class Factory : AndroidInjector.Factory<YourApplication>
}
```

And now, `viewModelFactory` is ready for you to inject into your Fragment, Activity, ....

*YourFragment.kt*

```
class YourFragment: Fragment() {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: Factory
}
```